# variables in vba search function

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have been working on this Function for awhile and can't seem to get it to work, nor have I been able to find any posts that have helped solve my particular issue.

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to find dates that could be in any of the columns A:G from Sheet4, using the Date value that is one cell to the left of my active cell in Sheet9.

The below code is what I have so far that worked when I had static values like (1/1/16) in my search, but does not work now that I am trying to use a variable. On the 2nd line of my with statement I just had .Select when I had static search terms and it worked, but once I added a variable I got the error "Object variable or With Block not Set", so I added ActiveCell in front of it, but that now just makes it pick whatever cell my cursor happens to be in. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub test()

Dim rFoundCell As Range
Dim vDate As Variant
Dim Expense As Worksheet
Dim Data As Worksheet

Set Expense = Sheet9
Set Data = Sheet4
Set rFoundCell = Range("A1")
Set vDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)


        Set rFoundCell = Data.Range("A:G").find(What:=vDate, After:=rFoundCell, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

         Sheet4.Activate

         With rFoundCell
            ActiveCell.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Copy
            Sheets("Expense Data").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         End With
```

Comment: what's the type of `vDate`? If it worked with a string literal input, did you try declaring it `As String` instead of `As Variant`? Also you need to handle the case where `rFoundCell` is `Nothing` - the `With` block will blow up with runtime error 91. @cyboashu bad advice, you don't `Set` a *value*, you `Set` an *object reference*.

Comment: agreed. didn't test on my end. Comment deleted!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Set vDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
> ```

Because you declared `vDate As Variant`, this `Set` instruction will assign an *object reference* pointing to a `Range` object.

Declare it with an actual data type, drop the `Set` statement, and assign it *a value* instead:

```
Dim vDate As String
vDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

Set rFoundCell = Data.Range("A:G").Find(...)
If rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

'rFoundCell cannot be Nothing if we're here
With rFoundCell
    .Select
    '...
End With
```

> *so I added ActiveCell in front of it, but that now just makes it pick whatever cell my cursor happens to be in*

Well, that's what `ActiveCell` does. Avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate` and referring to `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveCell`, at least implicitly.

> ```
> Set rFoundCell = Range("A1")
> ```

That `Range` call is implicitly referring to the active worksheet.

> ```
> Set Expense = Sheet9
> Set Data = Sheet4
> ```

You should rename `Sheet9` to `Expense`, and `Sheet4` to `Data` instead of coming up with new object references to hold copies of these references. Select the sheet in the Project Explorer, hit F4 and change the `(name)` property to something meaningful.